# Query Having Multiple Counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(SEQ_NBR INT, TERR_CD NVARCHAR(20), DSTR_CD NVARCHAR(20), RGN_CD NVARCHAR(20), AREA_CD NVARCHAR(20), CNTR_CD NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1, 'TERR A', 'DSTR A', 'RGN A', 'AREA A', 'BUS CNTR A')
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1, 'TERR B', 'DSTR A', 'RGN A', 'AREA A', 'BUS CNTR A')
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1, 'TERR C', 'DSTR B', 'RGN A', 'AREA A', 'BUS CNTR A')
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1, 'TERR A2', 'DSTR A2', 'RGN A2', 'AREA A2', 'BUS CNTR A2')
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1, 'TERR B2', 'DSTR B2', 'RGN A2', 'AREA A2', 'BUS CNTR A2')
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2, 'TERR C', 'DSTR B', 'RGN A', 'AREA A', 'BUS CNTR A')
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2, 'TERR D', 'DSTR C', 'RGN B', 'AREA A', 'BUS CNTR A')
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2, 'TERR B2', 'DSTR B2', 'RGN A2', 'AREA A2', 'BUS CNTR A2')

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

Now, I need the output like this:

```
SEQ_NBR TERR_NM TERR_CNT    DSTR_NM DSTR_CNT    RGN_CD  RGN_CNT AREA_CD AREA_CNT    CTR_CD  CTR_CNT
1   TERR A  1       DSTR A  2       RGN A   3   AREA A  3       BUS CNTR A  3
1   TERR B  1       DSTR A  2       RGN A   3   AREA A  3       BUS CNTR A  3
1   TERR C  1       DSTR B  1       RGN A   3   AREA A  3       BUS CNTR A  3
1   TERR A2 1       DSTR A2 1       RGN A2  2   AREA A2 2       BUS CNTR A2 2
1   TERR B2 1       DSTR B2 1       RGN A2  2   AREA A2 2       BUS CNTR A2 2
2   TERR C  1       DSTR B  1       RGN A   1   AREA A  2       BUS CNTR A  2
2   TERR D  1       DSTR C  1       RNG B   1   AREA A  2       BUS CNTR A  2
2   TERR B2 1       DSTR B2 1       RGN A2  1   AREA A2 1       BUS CNTR A2 1
```

Here, SEQ_NBR 1 is associated to 5 differenr TERR_CD, hence the TERR_CNT is 1. TERR_CD "A" and "B" belong to DSTR_CD A and TERR_CD "C" belongs to DSTR_CD B, so the count will be 2 for DSTR A and 1 for DSTR B. Similarly for RGN_CD "A", the count will be 3.

Could someone help me with the query?

Comment: Please learn to format your code after almost 10 posts

Comment: Formatted your code , and you updated this again without formatting?

Comment: Sorry, let me post this again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple:

```
SELECT 
  SEQ_NBR, 
  TERR_CD, 
  COUNT(*) over (PARTITION BY TERR_CD, SEQ_NBR) TERR_CNT,
  DSTR_CD,
  COUNT(*) over (PARTITION BY DSTR_CD, SEQ_NBR) DSTR_CNT,
  RGN_CD, 
  COUNT(*) over (PARTITION BY RGN_CD, SEQ_NBR) RGN_CNT,
  AREA_CD, 
  COUNT(*) over (PARTITION BY AREA_CD, SEQ_NBR) AREA_CNT,
  CNTR_CD,
  COUNT(*) over (PARTITION BY CNTR_CD, SEQ_NBR) CNTR_CNT
FROM @temp
```